# Dropbox.js how to download an specific revision? is it possible?

Tags: javascript, download, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using dropbox.js to upload the files from my web app to the cloud.

I noticed that if you upload two files with the same name, it just create another version or revision.

The thing is I dont found any way to "programatically" download an specific revision of the file.

Is there any workaround? Any help will be appreciated

I'm using this function to generate the download link:

```
function downFile(i) {
        var client = new Dropbox.Client({
            key: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            secret: "xxxxxxxxxx",
            sandbox: false,
            token: "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        });       
        client.makeUrl(i, {
            downloadHack: false
            }, function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error); // Something went wrong.
            }

                $("#mylink").html(data.url);
                $("#mylink").attr("href", data.url);

        });


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `dropbox.js`, the method to download a file is called `readFile`, and it takes an optional `rev` parameter to specify which revision of the file you want to access.

So something like `client.readFile(path, { rev: 'abc123' }, function (err, contents) { ... });` should work.

The code you have so far seems to be creating a share link for the file. There's no way to create a share link that points to a specific revision of the file... you'll always get the latest file contents from a share link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I'm looking at the documentation, but I can't understand how to use client.readFile() to download a file from the browser.

Comment: The callback receives the contents of the file. If you mean you want the user to then save a copy of that file to their local computer, maybe the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) is an option?